# Tricky String Normalization in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm sure this will be easy pickings for more experienced programmers than I, but this problem is bedeviling me and I've made a couple of failed attempts, so I wanted to see what other people might come up with.

I have about a hundred strings that look something like this:

```
(argument1 OR argument2) | inputlookup my_lookup.csv | `macro1(tag,bunit)` | `macro2(category)` | `macro_3(tag,\"expected\",category)` | `macro4(tag,\"timesync\")`
```

The goal is to find the arguments to the macro function and replace them with the count of the arguments, so that the final output looks like this:

```
(argument1 OR argument2) | inputlookup my_lookup.csv | `macro1(2)` | `macro2(1)` | `macro_3(3)` | `macro4(2)`
```

Python has ways of obtaining the count I need (I was simply counting up the number of commas in a string and adding 1), and Python has plenty of regex-type solutions for inline string replacement, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to combine them.

It seems something like `re.sub` won't let me identify a substring, count the number of commas in the substring, and then replace the substring with that value (unless I am missing something in the docs).

Can anybody think of a way to do this? Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
import re

def count_commas(input_str):
    c = 0
    for s in input_str:
        if s == ',':
            c += 1
    return c

pattern = r'\([A-Za-z0-9,""]+\)'
original_str = '(argument1 OR argument2) | inputlookup my_lookup.csv | `macro1(tag,bunit)` | `macro2(category)` | `macro_3(tag,\"expected\",category)` | `macro4(tag,\"timesync\")`'

matches = re.findall(pattern, original_str)

for match in matches:
    comma_count = count_commas(match) + 1
    match = match.replace('(', '\(').replace(')', '\)')
    original_str = re.sub(r'' + match, '(' + str(comma_count) + ')', original_str)

print (original_str)
```

**Explanation:**

`pattern` : "\([A-Za-z0-9,""]+\)" - backslashes to escape the special characters '(' and ')' in regex, and then I am looking for alphanumeric, comma and quotations (in the square-brackets) which is followed with '+' which means one or more than one repetition of such symbols in the square brackets.
`matches` : list of all the matches found. Eg - `(tag,bunit)`

Then, I am looping over all the matches to find the number of commas in the match, followed by replacing the '(' with '\(' and ')' with '\)' so as to escape in regex.
Finally, in the last line of the loop, I am using `re.sub` to replace the matched string with the comma count in the original string.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for replying.